# How to guessing $y_p$ of $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-y=\frac{2}{1+e^x}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE
$$\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-y=\dfrac{2}{1+e^x}.$$

I have tried to solve using undetermined coefficients.

Let $y=y_h+y_p$.

I can find the homogeneous solution, $y_h$ is $$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}.$$

Now I'm confused to determine $y_p$. I don't know guessing $y_p$ of $\dfrac{2}{1+e^x}$.

Any hint to determine $y_p$?

Comment: Why guess? to find $y_{p}$ you're supposed to plug in a solution of the form $y_{p} (x) = c_{1} (x) e^{x} + c_{2} (x) e^{-x}$ along with the condition $c_{1}' (x) e^{x} + c_{2}' (x) e^{-x} = 0$ and solve for the functions $c_{1} , c_{2} $ - this is what undetermined coefficients means.

Comment: @TomAriel what you're describing is the method of variation of parameters.

Comment: @A. E. Rosas Oh, sorry, somehow conflated them.

Comment: I vote to close this question because I think for solving this ODE we can easily use variation of parameters method rather than undetermined coefficients method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side does not have the format for the method of undetermined parameters. For that it would have to be a sum of terms $q_k(x)e^{\lambda_k x}$ where $q_i$ are polynomials and $λ_k$ may be complex (along with the coefficients of $q_i$, then the conjugate of the term will also be in the sum for a real-valued right side).

By a slight abuse of the method one could expand the given right side into a series that has terms of that format, for $x>0$ this would be
$$
\frac{2e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kx}.
$$
Then each term $2e^{-kx}$ contributes a term $a_1xe^{-x}$ and $a_ke^{-kx}$ for $k\ge 2$ where
$$
a_1=-1,~~a_k=\frac2{k^2-1}\text{ for }k\ge 2
$$
A similar approach works for $x<0$ where $|e^x|<1$.